# Sort list by reverse of strings

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the list of strings `s = ['az', 'by', 'cy', 'cx']`.

I would like to sort this list by the *reverse of each string*. Desired sort: `s = ['cx', 'by', 'cy', 'az']`. (Note: I am not looking for `s.sort(reverse=True)`)

One way to achieve this would be as:

```py
s = ['az', 'by', 'cy', 'cx']
reversed_s = [val[::-1] for val in s]
reversed_s.sort()
s = [val[::-1] for val in reversed_s]
```

This is fine. It works. But I'm still unsatisfied with the solution (reverse strings, sort, reverse back). Is there any better way of performing this sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ['az', 'by', 'cy', 'cx']
s.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```

You can pass a `key` to `sort` which will be used to remap each value. Same goes for `sorted` if you do not want to sort in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
>>> s = ['az', 'by', 'cy', 'cx']
>>> s.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])
>>> s
['cx', 'by', 'cy', 'az']
```